# Use multiple type parameters to return different types in different methods

Tags: java, generics, interpreter, return-type, visitor-pattern

I am writing an interpreter that uses the Visitor Pattern. I have Visitor interface with methods to visit all expressions and statements of the grammar. Here are two examples:

```
public interface Visitor {
    visitExpressionBinary(ExpressionBinary expressionBinary);
    visitStatementSleep(StatementSleep statementSleep);
}
```

Depending on the concrete implementation of visitors, I want to return different types in different methods. For example:

```
public VisitorA implements Visitor {
    int visitExpressionBinary(ExpressionBinary expressionBinary) { ... }
    void visitStatementSleep(StatementSleep statementSleep) { ... }
}


public VisitorB implements Visitor {
    Expression visitExpressionBinary(ExpressionBinary expressionBinary) { ... }
    Statement visitStatementSleep(StatementSleep statementSleep) { ... }
}
```

How could I implement this behavior? I was thinking to implement my Visitor like this:

```
public interface Visitor <V,W> {
    V visitExpressionBinary(ExpressionBinary expressionBinary);
    W visitStatementSleep(StatementSleep statementSleep);
}
```

and implementing the concrete visitors like this:

```
public VisitorA implements Visitor<Integer, Void> {
    Integer visitExpressionBinary(ExpressionBinary expressionBinary) { ... }
    Void visitStatementSleep(StatementSleep statementSleep) { ... }
}


public VisitorB implements Visitor<Expression, Statement> {
    Expression visitExpressionBinary(ExpressionBinary expressionBinary) { ... }
    Statement visitStatementSleep(StatementSleep statementSleep) { ... }
}
```

**Is that good Java programming?** Thanks!

Comment: How do you implement the accept methods/Visitable interface?

Comment: Good questions! For Statements: `public abstract <T,W> W accept(Visitor<T,W> visitor);`

Comment: If it solves your problems, it is fine.

Comment: It does solve my problem. I wanted to know if that is good Java programming. It compiles and everything, but is that something an experienced programmer would do? Or is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing the big picture of your use case. Usually, `target.accept(vistor)` is called where the dynamic types of both `target` and `visitor` are unknown, and the visitor pattern is used to do double-dispatch. In that case, `T,W` would be unknown too, and you cannot do much with the `W` return type. But your use case may differ.

Comment: What do you mean I cannot do much with `W`?